# Unable to boot or reinstall Ubuntu

Tags: boot, grub2, uefi

I have Win10 and Ubuntu 20.04 installed on different SSD. While upgrading my Ubuntu 20.10 there was a  power shut, thus upgrade likely failed. Now my system wont load.

At first I have tried to boot in recovery mode and it was just black screen. Then I have tried to boot win10. There was some error message offering me to restart. After restart and some automatic repair I cannot access even grub loader.

I have decided to boot from live USB with Kubuntu 18.04.5 LTS on it.
It halts (with nomodeset parameter). But every time on different messages. For example

" [7.317560] ahci 0000:00:17.0: AHCI 0001.0301 32 slots 6 ports 6Gbps 0x3f impl SATA mode "

" [7.590818] usb 1-4: SerialNumber: 907E0AF6  "

" [7.587522] e1000e 0000:00:1f.6 (uninitialized): registered PHC clock "

Without nomodeset parameter it is always " fb0: switching to noveaufb from EFI VGA "

I do not understand what can cause such behavior. What is the way to locate an error?

Secure boot is disabled. Windows boots and works fine. I have also tried to boot from Linux Mint 20 and boot-repair-disk and experienced same behavior.

Comment: same, it is today's update, I don't know how we can fix it

Comment: If you can't boot with three separate distributions, there's likely a hardware problem.  Do you know the cause of the power loss?  Perhaps the power loss coincided with hardware failure, or it may have been a symptom of hardware failure that has already occurred.  You may also want to verify that you have created installation media correctly and that it passes all verification/integrity checks.